# sort tab delimited file with header

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a file with a header specify with @blabla - different files have different number of header lines but they all specify the header lines by the @ sign.

I.e.,

```
@HI this is header line 1
@Bye this is header line 2
2 210 hi 1300 hl df de
9 179 hi 110 hl df de
2 190 hi 1310 hl df de
9 134 hi 190 hl df de
```

After the headers the file are tab-delimited.

Anyone knows an fast/easy way to sort this file in linux (possibly using sort command).

I'd like to sort it by the 1st (and then 4th) columns but keeping the header as the header in the sorted version.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the header, sort and then add the header

```
$ grep '^@' foo > foo.sorted; grep -v '^@' foo | sort --key=2,4 >> foo.sorted
$ cat foo.sorted 
@HI this is header line 1
@Bye this is header line 2
9 134 hi 190 hl df de
9 179 hi 110 hl df de
2 190 hi 1310 hl df de
2 210 hi 1300 hl df de
```

Answer (score -2):

```
awk 'NR<=2{print}NR>2{print|"sort -t\"    \" -k1,1n -k4,4n"}' foo.txt
```